# How do I index an pandas dataframe using boolean indexing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean-indexing

I am starting a new practice module in pandas where we deal with indexing and filtering of data. I have come across a format of method chaining that was not explained in the course and I was wondering if anyone could help me make sense of this. The dataset is from the fortune 500 company listings.

```
df = pd.read_csv('f500.csv', index_col = 0)
```

The issue is that we have been taught to use boolean indexing by passing the bool condition to the dataframe like so;

```
motor_bool = df["industry"] == "Motor Vehicles and Parts"
motor_countries = df.loc[motor_bool, "country"]
```

The above code was to find the countries that have "Motor Vehicles and Parts" as their industries. The last exercise in the module asks us to

*" Create a series, industry_usa, containing counts of the two most common values in the industry column for companies headquartered in the USA."*

And the answer code is

```
industry_usa = f500["industry"][f500["country"] == "USA"].value_counts().head(2)
```

I don't understand how we can suddenly use df[col]df[col] back to back? Am I not supposed pass the bool condition first then specify which column i want to assign it to using .loc? The method chaining the used is very different to what we have practiced.

Please help. I am truly confused.

As always, thanks you, stack community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think last solution is not [recommended](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters), here better is use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) like second solution for get column `industry` by mask and then get counts:

```
industry_usa = f500.loc[f500["country"] == "USA", "industry"].value_counts().head(2)
```

Another solution with [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

```
industry_usa = f500.loc[f500["country"] == "USA", "industry"].nlargest(2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly. Also thank you for consistently helping me with learning python. I have learned a lot from your comments. You are a pandas guru!

Comment: For some reason, when I tried the same thing using another mask it doesn't work?

```
boul = df['previous_rank'].isnull()

df.loc[df['previous_rank'].isnull()]

```

The code above only returns the column labels. Blank Dataframe

Comment: @Oscar Agbor Hard question, is DataFrame same? Or is possible no missing data? Or there are strings NaNs, so need `df.loc[df['previous_rank'] == 'NaN']`?

Comment: Yes it is the same DataFrame. Some rows have missing values.

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

Comment: @Oscar Agbor Can you test if missing values in `previous_rank` column by `df['previous_rank'].isnull().sum()`? Because if use  ``` df.isnull().sum() ``` it test all columns, so possible no missing values in `previous_rank` column